# What is the best way to embed html's and Images and JavaScript's into browser control

Tags: c++, webbrowser-control, winapi

I will be using Win32++ to create my GUI in windows xp/vista/7
Its going to be simple browser that need to embed static web site , my question is:
How can I embed the static web site in to single exe that contains the browser control.

Comment: Re-word the question. Are you trying to make a browser like app that contains one site, of make a static site that some one can use with say firefox or chrome? Dose this need to be net-enabled? is it actually anything to do with embedded systems?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to host MSHTML, the core component of Internet Explorer.

You'll have to include your static webpage as an EXE resource, and use the [res:// protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767740.aspx) to name your website parts.